# Java swing drawLine and drawRect not drawing in correct positions

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I am trying to draw a network representation with javax swing via data from a file. I have a central hub at (100,100) and several local hubs which I wish to connect with lines. However, the local hubs are being placed too far (but still appear to be proportionally larger for all elements) and the lines do not meet at the same place, even though one set of their (x,y) coords are set to be (100,100).

local hub drawer class:

```
public class hub_drawer extends JComponent{
String label;
int x;
int y;

public hub_drawer(String hub_number, int xCoord, int yCoord){
    label = hub_number;
    x = xCoord;
    y = yCoord;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    g2.setColor(Color.green);
    g2.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
    g2.drawLine(100, 100, x, y);

    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.drawString(label,x+6,y-1);
}
```

frame class:

```
public class frame{
public static void main(String [] args){

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Faux Broadband Network");
    f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f.add(new central_hub());
    f.setVisible(true);
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hubs.txt"));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);

        while (sc.hasNext()){
            String hubnum = sc.next();
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%s %d %d \n", hubnum, x, y);
            f.add(new hub_drawer(hubnum, x, y));
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        sc.close();
        br.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

The printf function is used to ensure that the correct data is being input. The output for the print function is the exact same as the file data.

[What it should look like (excluding the extra lines coming from the local hubs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGPpV.png)

[image]

[What mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUR21.jpg)

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the text file.

Comment: You seem to be trying to draw elements in virtual space but are forgetting that a component itself has it's own concept of position (and size), so your drawings are probably been offset by the position of the component ... at a guess.  What I would consider doing is using a single component to render ALL the hubs and lines

Comment: Code your "x and y" components as per your screen resolution. You have taken frame size as "f.setSize(500, 500);" which is too short for 1080p screen. As you moving towards increased pixels, your UI built on smaller resolution start decreasing in size.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

`convertPoint(source,x,y,destination)`

It will do the thing for you.